# Can't use DataContractSerializer - assembly mismatch?

Tags: c#, xna, xml-serialization, windows-phone-7.1, assembly-references

I'm trying to use the `DataContractSerializer` to save some data in the `IsolatedStorage`, however I've met some unexpected problems. After adding the serializer to the code, I get the following errors during building:

> Error 3   The type 'System.Xml.XmlWriter' is defined in an assembly that
>   is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Xml,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. C:\Users\Dániel\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2012\Projects\GameLibs\SpaceshipConquest\SpaceshipConquest\SpaceshipConquest\Model\GameState.cs   47  13  SpaceshipConquest
>
> Error 4   The type 'System.Xml.XmlReader' is defined in an assembly that
>   is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Xml,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. C:\Users\Dániel\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2012\Projects\GameLibs\SpaceshipConquest\SpaceshipConquest\SpaceshipConquest\Model\GameState.cs   62  21  SpaceshipConquest

Since the `System.Xml` assembly is already referenced I've tried to change the reference version in the project file - but this lead to a new error during runtime:

> File or assembly name 'System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089', or one of its
>   dependencies, was not found.

Any idea how to solve this?

Edit: I've tried setting every assembly version to 4.0.0.0, but it seems that they would also need the System.dll's 4.0.0.0 version, which I can not set.

Edit 2: I've also tried copying over the .cs files to a new project, but that didn't solve the problem either.

Comment: Right, so no comments, no questions, no answers... T_T

Comment: Well, yeah, because the error message was quite specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved, after much trial the slution was adding

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
```

to the header of the .cs file. It seems that even though the assembly was imported, it couldn't use the XmlSerializer without specifying that I'm using it's assembly.